# Change fontsize of table vs figure

Tags: captions, templates, styles

I'm using a template provided by a conference, that doesn't follow its own style guide.

The table caption should be normalsize and the figure caption should be footnotesize.

Below I have tried to add an ifx statement to the cls file, what am I doing wrong?

```tex
%% New caption command
\newcommand\@MaxCapWidth{5.5in}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{.1in}
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{.15in}
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \ifx\@captype @table%
    \normalsize
  \else%
    \footnotesize
  \fi
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1. #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\@MaxCapWidth
    \hskip.5in\parbox{5.5in}{#1. #2}
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip\normalsize}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing `\@captype` to the following `@` which is clearly false, and the true branch is never used. You probably want something like

```
\def\@tempa{table}%
\ifx\@captype\@tempa
  \normalsize
\else
  \footnotesize
\fi
```